# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'unfetch'

Tags: reactjs

My first time using react and [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch) and im following a course. Couldnt find a solution on this particularly.

So i import unfetched with

```
import fetch from 'unfetch';
```

But when i run  `yarn start`
i get

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'unfetch' in 'C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\demo\js\src'

when i hover over unfetch in my code it says module "c:/Users/yigit/Desktop/demo/js/node_modules/unfetch/src/index"
and the folder does exist and unfetch is in my package.json as

> "unfetch": "^5.0.0",

Has anyone else encountered it and how can i solve it?

Btw: i did run `npm fix audit` didnt work.

Comment: delete your `node_modules` and `yarn install` again

Comment: How do you run your app?

Comment: @Konrad yarn start or npm start. Both give the same error.

Comment: The command that is actually running when you run `npm start` is located in `package.json`

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/developit/unfetch/pull/164

version 5.0.0 has an export bug

because of that I am using version 4.2.0

Comment: I used the info from your comment, guessing that it is what you should have [edit]ed into the post yourself to turn it into an answer. Please review.